# Can steema teechart replace Decision Cube?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, teechart

I am using Decision Cube in Delphi VCL Application made in Delphi 2010. However now application has to be  compiled on Delphi XE5 platform and I am not able to install the decision cube on Win 7 Delphi XE5. Hence I am looking forward to replace the decision cube controls with steema charts. So can you please suggest if Steema software teechart is right alternative?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's little analogy between the two components. TeeChart provides charting and the Decision Cube provided data analysis. Off the top of my head, DevExpress offer their PivotGrid component and Fast Reports offer a FastCube component that will provide the same functionality as TDecisionCube and more.

Comment: Actually there's a little link between both tools. TeeChart includes its specific charting packages for Decision Cube. Not that they replace Decision Cube though as Decision Cube packages are necessary for the TeeChart Decision Cube packages to run.